# What's the reason for the use of delegates in WF4?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Why does WF4 use this pattern (callbacks via delegates)?

```
app.Idle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs o)
{    
    syncEvent.Set();
};
```

Comment: Its a substantial edit, but your question seems to have absolutely nothing to do with asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

It's easier than writing a separate method, and it allows you to access the `syncEvent` local variable without writing a separate class with a field (see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html) for more information).